# i have this error when I try to run rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
mac@MacBook-Pro-de-mac myapp % rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.2.2 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on tcp://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2020-03-21 03:37:55 +0000
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _PQresultMemorySize
  Referenced from: /Users/mac/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _PQresultMemorySize
  Referenced from: /Users/mac/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib

zsh: abort      rails s

FATAL: prematurely zombied
mac@MacBook-Pro-de-mac myapp %
```

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling the `pg` gem.

Comment: it was problem thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using postgresql ? If so do following:

```
brew uninstall postgresql
brew install postgresql
```

Comment: right postgresql was missing it's work now thank you